# Getting segmentation fault with this code but I'm not sure how to fix it

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm getting segmentation fault here when I try to run the program with for example these numbers:

17 56 
2748 55539 24890 4564
1995 44437 39060 75810
2583 49463 73827 24420
395 46500 56779 60559
273 30090 78489 37881
950 76442 92020 15157
756 85200 19627 13615
1787 79756 51484 34462
1424 65520 83527 74748
2738 10501 9678 95956
2250 92554 55640 91863
2402 84001 72097 92122
1223 71750 71493 12744
164 99321 73824 93276
1057 96262 24703 68502
1649 76765 48873 18181
2552 49371 32960 81865

I have a feeling it may have to do something with scanf but I'm not sure what it is.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int holes;
        int p;
        scanf("%d %d", &holes, &p);
        double plates = (double) p;
        int* R[holes];
        int* X[holes];
        int* Y[holes];
        int* Z[holes];
        double sizeOfPlate[p];
        for(int i = 0; i < holes; i++){
                scanf("%d %d %d %d", R[i], X[i], Y[i], Z[i]);
        }

        if(holes == 0){
                for(int i = 0; i < p; i++){
                        sizeOfPlate[i] = 100 / plates;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < p; ++i)
                {
                        printf("%.9lf\n", sizeOfPlate[i]);
                }
        }
        else if(p == 1)
                printf("100.0000000");
        else{
                printf("Wrong result");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should always check the return value of `scanf`. Your input might be spoiled by some remaining `'\n'` which you will never notice if you don't care about this return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
    int* R[holes];
    int* X[holes];
    int* Y[holes];
    int* Z[holes];
```

all are arrays of pointers, but in itself, these pointers do not point to any valid memory. Unless a valid memory is pointed to by each of these pointers in these arrays, using them as argument to `scanf()` will lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Segmentation fault is one of the side effects.

You need to either

- point these pointers to some valid memory (sing allocator function like [`malloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc))
- make the arrays of type `int` instead of `int *` and then use the address of each element as argument to `scanf()`.

Comment: To expand on this answer: the seg fault happens when this line is executed:  scanf("%d %d %d %d", R[i], X[i], Y[i], Z[i]);